# Generating a complete XSD file from a VS2010 DSL project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, xsd, dsl

I would like to read an XML model file generated by a Visual Studio 2010 DSL project in a program run outside of Visual Studio. I was planning to use xsd.exe to generate a C# class based on the XML schema output by the Dsl\DomainSchema.tt template. However, this template produces an XSD file that is missing many of the types present in the .dsl file.

Is this a bug, or do I need to do something special to make sure all types are included in the generated schema?

Comment: Is there any difference you can tell between the types that are included and the ones that aren't?  E.g. I know that when a WCF service auto-generates WSDLs/XSDs, it only includes DataContracts that are actually exposed by the service.  Perhaps something similar is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio 2010 CMD and check the options of `xsd /?` You can see the `type` option, by default it is looking at all types in the assembly already:

```
/type:<type>
    Type from assembly to generate schema for. Multiple types may be provided.
    If no types are provided, then schemas for all types in an assembly
    are generated. Short form is '/t:'.
```